# InvalidArgumentException: json_decode error: Syntax error

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm upgrading from Laravel 6 to 7 and when I run phpunit I get this error in some tests

```
InvalidArgumentException: json_decode error: Syntax error
```

But if in the ReindexJob.php file I change the function

```
public function handle(): void
{
   $this->channel->items()->searchable();
}
```

to

```
public function handle(): void
{
   $this->channel->items();
}
```

I no longer have the error, but this line should not be changed.

My composer.json is here

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
        "dingo/api": "^3.0",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.2",
        "socialiteproviders/slack": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^2.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.10",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "jaspaul/eloquent-model-validation": "^2.0",
        "soapbox/goodtalk-settings": "^2.0",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "socialiteproviders/microsoft-graph": "^2.0",
        "layershifter/tld-extract": "^1.2",
        "spatie/laravel-query-builder": "^2.1",
        "microsoft/microsoft-graph": "^1.1",
        "soapbox/signed-requests": "^4.2",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "laravel/horizon": "^4.3",
        "jaspaul/eloquent-sti": "^2.0",
        "jshayes/fake-requests": "^4.1",
        "laravel/cashier": "^10.0",
        "soapbox/truncator": "^1.0",
        "soapbox/idempotency": "^5.0",
        "jshayes/laravel-datadogstatsd": "^2.0",
        "algolia/scout-extended": "^1.18",
        "segmentio/analytics-php": "^1.5",
        "art4/json-api-client": "^0.10.0",
        "soapbox/agenda-template-client": "^6.0",
        "league/csv": "^9.7",
        "vinkla/hashids": "^8.1",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0",
        "socialiteproviders/microsoft-azure": "^3.0",
        "joypixels/emoji-toolkit": "^6.0.1",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.4.7",
        "league/mime-type-detection": "^1.4",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^2.3",
        "soapbox/laravel-rollout": "^3.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^2.7"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "1.0.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~8.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.0",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.6",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.1",
        "brianium/paratest": "~3.0",
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.5",
        "dms/phpunit-arraysubset-asserts": "^0.1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate",
            "php artisan jwt:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "./scripts/install-git-hooks"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "vendor/bin",
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "dingo/api"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Apparently everything is correct here.
And some files with the same test are passing, but it can't be, because they are practically identical.

Comment: I'm afraid, we need more information. What is `searchable()`?

Comment: I'm assuming that's Laravel Scout's `searchable()` did you also upgrade scout to work with Laravel 7?

Comment: My version of Laravel Scout's is the 1.18

Comment: And I'm using algolia/scout-extended

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade (which you should be following) says you need scout v8 for Laravel 7

Comment: The project contains Laravel Scout's v8

Comment: @user16463899 Show us your `composer.json` please.

Comment: I edited my question with a composer.json

Comment: @user16463899: Maybe check your last edit, it looks cutted/incomplete. And I suggest you provoke the error with your original code while taking a look with a step-debugger (e.g. xdebug), json encode/decode errors normally show that some data (from a different place) is malformed and the place of cause normally is not he cause of error nor give such messages alone good hints (probably with any of the library projects you have in use, having a break-point on the error should show the stacktrace in the debug client).

Comment: Everything works correctly, but in tests it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using xdebug and tried looking into what triggers the InvalidArgumentException in concrete? Especially as you can reproduce in tests, this is normally straight forward the moment you have a debugging setup. It's perhaps just some data you have in testing only.

Comment: Yes, I am going to try.